# Connecting earth wire with motor water pump

Tags: grounding

I am going to rewire my house and at present we have no earth wire anywhere in our house. Even the wires/cables available here in the market only have one phase wire and one neutral wire in them. So I am going to take an earth wire from the distribution box (which I am going to have installed) to all the outlets in our home. I have two questions:

Q1: Can we connect the earth wire with the motor water pump in our house? The motor pipe go more than 150 ft underground right down to the water. Will it be safe? Our motor pump is like this except that this is a hand-use water pump and we have an electric one at home:

http://images.wisegeek.com/hand-water-pump.jpg

Q2: Suppose the earth wire from the main panel is connected to one outlet (with its earth pin). Now to connect the second outlet with the earth wire, can we connect its earth pin with the previous outlet's earth pin?

I am from Pakistan and here we have 220-240 single phase wire and one neutral wire to the meter.

Comment: Generally speaking, multiple questions should go in multiple posts even if related like these.  The reasoning is if you get multiple answers for the multiple questions, there is no way to accept both answers.

Comment: You should also mention your location, at least the country.

Comment: I have edited the question now..

Comment: Do you have such a thing as copper grounding rods?

Comment: Can you get RCDs or RCBOs?

Comment: @Sparky256, why do you ask about ground rods? They have nothing to do with circuit grounds or clearing faults.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey. Cool it Speedy. The OP only mentioned if certain grounding options were valid. The OP has not replied, and it does not matter if he does or not. There was a 50% chance they had no such thing as a grounding rod, it was just a question. There is nothing wrong with asking a question.

Comment: @Sparky256, "Cool it"?? Seriously? ....... There is also nothing wrong with making a relevant comment. If you don't like it ignore me.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel we ELCB here but haven't seen an RCD anywhere yet

Comment: @Sparky256 we might have in d city but I was told by someone that since we live in a mountain area therefore ground roda wont ground properly unless they are buried very deep

Comment: @Saad, my point was that a ground rod has nothing to do with clearing faults and the regular workings of a circuit. The "ground" (dirt) outside and the grounding pin in a receptacle or green wire in a circuit are not at all the same thing.

Comment: @Saad. That makes perfect sense Saad.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey But isn't that green wire ultimately connected to that ground rod?

Comment: No, the green circuit ground is ultimately connected to the main panel which is where the main binding jumper is. That is where the equipment ground comes from. The fact that the grounding electrodes are also connected there is merely incidental. The two systems, while connected to the same place serve two very different functions.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: I would look at American bonding rules, in terms of what is legal as a ground rod.

Q2: I recommend pigtailing your grounds.  That is, one wire comes from the panel, a second wire travels to the next outlet, and a third short wire goes to this outlet.   All three wires are spliced together using whatever method is legal.   The reason to "pigtail" is that you need to be able to remove an outlet for repair, without breaking the grounds to downstream outlets.

Here are the best practices in the US, which are about as good as anywhere in the world. We create a well-established ground/earth connection with ground rods or bonding to a water pipe.  This ground wire goes to the main electrical panel (which contains the circuit breakers or fuses).

As it happens, in the US we bond neutral to ground. That is debatable, best to follow local codes.  If this is done, do it in the main panel only! Do not bond at sub-panels or other locations, and never misuse ground as a neutral.

From the panel, we use metal conduit, or run a ground wire to every outlet, junction box, switch etc. in our system.  If the ground is being added later, it may be run separate from the other wires via any workable route, as long as the wire is not in danger of physical damage.

For 30A or smaller circuits, US practice uses ground wire the same size as the main wire (bigger is allowed).  For larger cables, or in Europe, the practice is to allow a somewhat smaller ground wire.

Answer (score 0):

To your Q1: I would check which power grid is used in your country, normally (at my place) it is TN-C network. The earth (grounding) has the purpose that in any case of a leak current to ground the circuit breaker has to switch off. For that a connection outside your internal network is needed (grounding).

When the pipes are isolated to earth I do not recommend you to attach it. You need to be sure that the pipes are not isolated.

Q2: I do not understand this question enough to answer it. Maybe you could attach a schematic?

Comment: I am from Pakistan and I've edited the question. The pipes are not isolated. They are connected with each other right down to where the underground water is flowing. So if I connect the earth wire with it,  will it be safe for people? Any risk of electricution/shock if anyone touches it?

Comment: What I mean is,  suppose an earth wire is attached with the pump.  From there its going to panel,  and then to the first power outlet where I plug in stuff. Can that same wire goes to the next power outlet as well? Or separate earth wires are needed for separate outlets?